# Arduino: Any reason to have call Serial.end()?

Tags: arduino

I have a few sensors that are plugged into my mega. They are accessed via Serial and Serial2, etc.

My board reads the sensors once every X minutes then submits a POST request to my server. `delay(X * 60 * 1000)` is used to poll for the waiting period.

This is what my getPH() method looks like:

```
void getPH() {
  //<1>
  char inchar;
  while (Serial3.available()) {
    inchar = (char)Serial3.read();
    if (inchar != '\r') {
      phSensorString += inchar;
    }
  }
  //<2>
}
```

Now from a performance's perspective is it advisable that I insert `Serial3.begin()` at <1> and `Serial3.end()` at <2>? I've seen this pattern in other people's code. What effect will not doing so have on my board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason to ever call end() is if you have some method to make use of those IO pins for some other task.  So if outside the getPH() function you could use those 2 IO pins for another purpose, then the pattern you show makes sense.  Otherwise, it makes no sense to "allocate" and "deallocate" the serial port again and again and again and again...

While the pattern will function, I would advise that using begin() and end() in that pattern is mostly detrimental:

- you waste execution time in begin() and end()
- wastes code size including end() in the binary - remember the linker will only include functions that are called.

The good pattern for serial is to call begin() once in setup and never call end().

For a desktop environment, people learn that allocating and freeing resources is good behavior.  Partly because that allows sharing with other processes on the system.
For an embedded system there is no other processes to share with - your program is everything.  A robust pattern is opposite the desktop: allocate everything you will ever use at boot.

Comment: thanks that's the level of detailness I was looking for!